# I am trying to implement typedarray for drawables array

Tags: android, arrays, android-drawable, typed-arrays

I tried different ways through simple int[] then Typed array now my Typed array is giving resource id as 2130837586. How do I convert it to in the form of `R.drawable`? And if I tried to use `getDrawable` it gives this :

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@42007a80
```

I checked these in logcat.

Edit - ids.getIndexCount() is also zero.

This is my code. Please Help

```
     GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, getResources().obtainTypedArray((R.array.image_ids))));
```

this is my string

```
      <array name="image_ids">
    <item>@drawable/one</item>
    <item>@drawable/two</item>
    <item>@drawable/three</item>
    <item>@drawable/four</item>
    <item>@drawable/five</item>
    <item>@drawable/six</item>
    <item>@drawable/seven</item>
    <item>@drawable/eight</item>
    <item>@drawable/nine</item>
    <item>@drawable/ten</item>
    <item>@drawable/eleven</item>
    <item>@drawable/twelve</item>
</array>
```

Here is my ImageAdapter

```
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
TypedArray ids;

public ImageAdapter(Context con,TypedArray rids){
    mContext = con;
    ids = rids;
    Log.d("Check this out,",""+ids.getDrawable(0));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ids.getIndexCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ids.getDrawable(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(ids.getResourceId(position,-1));

     return imageView;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share ImageAdapter code

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah Updated my question.

Comment: if your ids array count is zero your problem is with loading the array from resources...

Comment: if i try int[] it gives 12 size but elements are zero.

Comment: so you got `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`, and what do you want to get?

Comment: something like R.drawable. so i can setImagesource

Comment: you have a `Drawable` then use `setImageDrawable`

Comment: It also didnt work gave error of nosuchmethod

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

imgIcon.setImageResource(ids[position]);